# How do I get the character from a read()

Tags: c

I am trying to copy a file to print it backwards using only `open()`, `read()`, and `write()`.
However I was wondering if there is a way to get the char pointer from the read which returns the number of bytes read. If so how do I go about doing that I have tried once but I ended up with an error

```
error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’ (have ‘ssize_t’)
```

This was the code snippet i was using

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
 if(argc != 3)/*argc should be 2 for correct execution*/
 {
  printf("usage: %s filename",argv[0]);
 }
 else
 {
  int file1 = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
  if(file1 == -1){
    printf("\nfailed to open file.");
    return 1;
  }
  int reversefile = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY, O_CREAT);
  int size =(int)lseek(file1, 0, SEEK_END)+1;
  char file2[size];
  int count=size;
  int i = 0;

  while(read(file1, &file2[count], 1) != 0)
  {
   *file2[i]=*read(file1, file[count], 1);
   write(reversefile, file2[i], size+1);
   count--;
   i++;
   lseek(reversefile, i, SEEK_SET);
   }
}
```

Comment: create a read and write file. Did i type that wrong?

Comment: Is there any need for you to read the output file?

Comment: not really i will change it to wronly

Answer (score 0):

`read` returns a `size_t` value indicating how many bytes are successfully read, it doesn't return a pointer.

For your purpose, you first need to call `read` with

```
read(file1, &file2[count], 1)
```

then you can access the value read from file by

```
file2[i] = file[count];
```

and I don't think you need to call `read` twice.

Further, if you only want one single char, they using `getc` is better.

```
char c;
while((c=getc(file1)) != EOF){
  // use c
}
```

Comment: thank  you for your answer. However i dont think the file2[i] = file count would get me the characters i needed. I uploaded all my code to make it clearer. I want to go through the file and read it char by char and recreate it backwards in another file. I took out the second read which makes sense after I read through it however I am still not sure how to get the characters and assign them to an array.

Comment: @user2872131 edited, did you miss the `&` in the post? otherwise it won't compile for me.

Comment: I added the `&` but it still doesnt compile and i get the same error. what does the `&` do btw? also is there another way to get the character into the array because i agree i might not need the second read but how else would i get the character?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to read all lines from your file and save them to array of strings.
   This is an array of 100 strings and each string can have up to 999 characters + 1('\0')

   ```
   char myfile[100][1000]
   ```
2. You need to reverse strings. This can be done with very easy algorithm. For example: if you string is "ABCDE" you swap 'A' and 'E', 'B' and 'D'. Every time you get with your for loot to strlen(myfile[i])/2 and you swap character on i-th position and (strlen(myfile[i]) - 1 - i-th)-th position.
3. Now you can write in your output.txt file all strings but in reverse order.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>

   char myfile[100][1000];
   int n;

   void readmyfile(void)
   {
       int i;
       FILE *input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
       printf("This is in your file:\n");
       for(i = 0; fscanf(input, "%[^\n] ", myfile[i]) != EOF; i++)
           printf("%s\n", myfile[i]);
       n = i;
       fclose(input);
   }

   void reverseall(void)
   {
       int i, j, len;
       char swap;
       for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
       {
           len = strlen(myfile[i]);
           for(j = 0; j < len / 2; j++)
           {
               swap = myfile[i][j];
               myfile[i][j] = myfile[i][len - 1 - j];
               myfile[i][len - 1 - j] = swap;
           }
       }
   }

   void writetooutput(void)
   {
       int i;
       FILE *output = fopen("output.txt", "w");
       printf("This is your output file:\n");
       for(i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
       {
           fprintf(output, "%s\n", myfile[i]);
           printf("%s\n", myfile[i]);
       }
       fclose(output);
   }

   int main()
   {
       readmyfile();
       reverseall();
       writetooutput();
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse? For fun, a recursive solution.  No need for `stat()` or `seek()`.

Notice `ssize_t len = read(inf, buf, N);`.  `len`, if >= 0 is the number of bytes read,  else an error occurred.  `len` as 0 usually indicates end-of-file.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int read_R(int inf, size_t N) {  // return 0 is good, else error
  int result = 0;
  char *buf = malloc(N);
  if (buf == NULL) {
    return -1;  // Out of memory
  }
  ssize_t len = read(inf, buf, N);
  if (len > 0) {
    // read & print remainder of file
    result = read_R(inf, N*2);
    // print this buffer in reverse
    while (len > 0) {
      putchar(buf[--len]);
    }
  }
  free(buf);
  if (len < 0) { // Some I/O error, see errno
    return 1;
  }
  return result;
}

// Usage
int inf = open(...);
if (read_R(inf, 4096)) {
  ; // error
}
else {
  ; // OK, every thing read and printed in reverse, memory free'd
}
close(inf);
```